# OpenID and Individual User Accounts in same MVC application

Tags: model-view-controller, openid-connect

I want to have an MVC application support individual user accounts for external users and accept tokens from ADFS using an OpenID endpoint for employees.

I created 2 mvc applications. One is setup to use OpenId only and it works correctly by redirecting me to the on-premises ADFS server and sets a cookie so I am authorized to a controller decorated with the [Authorize] attribute.

I have another mvc application on the same server as the first mvc site which is setup to use individual user accounts. I have added code in the Startup.Auth to add OpenId Connect to the OWIN pipeline.

```
      public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // Configure the db context, user manager and signin manager to use a single instance per request
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);

        // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
        // and to use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
        // Configure the sign in cookie
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {
                // Enables the application to validate the security stamp when the user logs in.
                // This is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an external login to your account.  
                OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                    validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                    regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
            }
        });            
        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

        // Enables the application to temporarily store user information when they are verifying the second factor in the two-factor authentication process.
        app.UseTwoFactorSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorCookie, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));

        // Enables the application to remember the second login verification factor such as phone or email.
        // Once you check this option, your second step of verification during the login process will be remembered on the device where you logged in from.
        // This is similar to the RememberMe option when you log in.
        app.UseTwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie);

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
           new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
           {
               ClientId = clientId,
               MetadataAddress = metadataAddress,
               RedirectUri = redirectUri,
               //PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri
           });

    }
```

I assumed this was all I needed to user OpenID in this second application.
I first access the first mvc (OpenId only) application and sign in. I can access authorized controller actions on that application.
I then try to access the second application (individual user accounts and OpenID) and assumed I would be authorized.

Instead I get redirected a few times between the ADFS server and the mvc app until the "Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.InvalidRequestException: MSIS7042: The same client browser session has made '6' requests in the last '1' seconds. " error gets thrown.

A fiddler trace shows: 
302 TestApp2 
200 adfs server 
302 TestApp2 
302 TestApp2 
200 adfs server 
etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this working using this Startup.ConfigureAuth.

```
        public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);

        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
         new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
         {
             ClientId = clientId,
             MetadataAddress = metadataAddress,
             RedirectUri = redirectUri,
                //PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri
            });

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {
                OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                    validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                    regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
            }
        });

        app.UseTwoFactorSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorCookie, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));

        app.UseTwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie);


    }
```